# MongoDB FailedToParse: Bad characters in value

Tags: json, mongodb, bson, database-restore

I have a simple mongodb database. I'm dumping using mongodump.

dump command

```
mongodump --db user_profiles --out /data/dumps/user-profiles
```

Here is the content of the user_profiles database. It has one collection (user_data) consisting of the following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555a882a722f2a009fc136e4"), "username" : "thor", "passwd" : "*1D28C7B35C0CD618178988146861D37C97883D37", "email" : "thor@avengers.com", "phone" : "4023331000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555a882a722f2a009fc136e5"), "username" : "ironman", "passwd" : "*626AC8265C7D53693CB7478376CE1B4825DFF286", "email" : "tony@avengers.com", "phone" : "4023331001" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555a882a722f2a009fc136e6"), "username" : "hulk", "passwd" : "*CB375EA58EE918755D4EC717738DCA3494A3E668", "email" : "hulk@avengers.com", "phone" : "4023331002" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555a882a722f2a009fc136e7"), "username" : "captain_america", "passwd" : "*B43FA5F9280F393E7A8C57D20648E8E4DFE99BA0", "email" : "steve@avengers.com", "phone" : "4023331003" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("555a882a722f2a009fc136e8"), "username" : "daredevil", "passwd" : "*B91567A0A3D304343624C30B306A4B893F4E4996", "email" : "daredevil@avengers.com", "phone" : "4023331004" }
```

After copying the dump to a nfs and then trying to load the dump into a test server using mongorestore

```
mongorestore --host db-test --port 27017 /remote/dumps/user-profiles
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Mon May 18 20:19:23.918         going into namespace [user_profiles.user_data]
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset:30
```

How to resolve this FailedToParse Error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To do further testing I created a test_db with a test_collection that only had one simple value 'x':1, and even that didn't work. So I knew something else had to be going on.

**Versions of your tools matters**

The version of mongodump that was being used was 3.0.3. The version on another virtual machine that was using mongorestore was 2.4.x. This was the cause for the errors. Once I got the mongodb-org-tools updated on my virtual machine ([see official guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)) I was able to get up and running as expected.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future. Check your versions!

```
mongodump --version
mongorestore --version
```

Comment: I have to wait the required two days before I can answer my own question, but I plan on it. Thanks.